# Graphics drivers for Intel NUC Hades Canyon NUC8i7HVK (AMD Radeon RX Vega GH)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, radeon, intel-nuc

I know this is a commonly asked question, but I am having trouble with this..

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I have had to use `nomodeset` parameters in grub on boot to have boot correctly.

`uname -mrs`

```
Linux 4.15.0-23-generic x86_64
```

`lspci | grep VGA`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega [Radeon RX Vega M] (rev c0)
```

Running `ubuntu drivers devices` gives no results

`lshw -c video`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: c0
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:db500000-db53ffff memory:c0000-dffff

   *-display UNCLAIMED
   description: Display controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef iomemory:2f0-2ef memory:2ffe000000-2ffeffffff memory:2fa0000000-2fafffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

I tried adding `amdgpu.dc=1` to boot params but doesn't change anything.

`glmark2`

```
=======================================================                                                
glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d                                                               
=======================================================
OpenGL Information
GL_VENDOR:     VMware, Inc.
GL_RENDERER:   llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 18.0.0-rc5
```

-- EDIT --

Upgraded to kernel 4.16 and no changes, although running glmark2 is less intensive on the CPU

Comment: I'm going through this exact same process for Ubuntu 18.04 on mine and seeing the same results. Also tried installing the proprietary drivers (AMD says they're for 16.04) without luck. A fresh Fedora 28 install (skip the nomodeset dance) also only has llvmpipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I posted a writeup at 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400400
with the instructions updated for 4.19-rc2.

Here's my original answer:

Here's what I did to get it working today on ubuntu 18.04 (from memory, probably with typos):

a) Install latest mesa from https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

b) Followed https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds
using http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-06-08/

i.e.:

```
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-06-08/linux-modules-4.17.0-999-generic_4.17.0-999.201806080237_amd64.deb
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-06-08/linux-image-unsigned-4.17.0-999-generic_4.17.0-999.201806080237_amd64.deb
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-06-08/linux-headers-4.17.0-999-generic_4.17.0-999.201806080237_amd64.deb
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-06-08/linux-headers-4.17.0-999_4.17.0-999.201806080237_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i linux*201806080237*.deb
```

c) Rebooted and noticed error in /var/log/kern.log about no firmware, so installed that:

```
$ wget -m -np https://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/vegam/
$ sudo cp people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/vegam/*.bin /lib/firmware/amdgpu
$ sudo /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -u -k all
```

and rebooted.

And it worked.  Having a working ssh connection to the machine made recovering from mistakes and black screens a lot easier.

A couple of odd glitches (fishgl.com's fish stopped moving once, and I got a crazy high result for furmark once), but it's been up and relatively snappy for at least half an hour now :-)

glxinfo reports

```
OpenGL renderer string: AMD VEGAM (DRM 3.26.0, 4.17.0-999-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.0-devel
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.2.0-devel
```

glmark2 reports a score of 10698 (vs. 2571 on i7-6700 with HD Graphics 530, and 2770 on Skull Canyon live ubuntu 18.04)

furmark 0.7 from pts8 reports 1718 at 1920x1080.

Your mileage may vary.  Your machine may explode.  Good luck!

Comment: From a fresh install this worked perfectly.

Comment: Warning, upgrading to kernel `4.17.1-041701-generic` reverts the graphics back to llvmpipe. Any thoughts? I tried running `update-initramfs` again but no change.

Comment: Step A today (June 13) makes my fresh install unable to boot. After having removed those packages I can now boot but login screen is laggy like hell.  Output from `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` yields `OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)`

Comment: Thanks for the warning about updating.  I knew there was a reason I didn't do 'sudo apt dist-upgrade' on that box :-)

Comment: To revert step A, see the oibaf ppa readme, e.g.:
`$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge; sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`

Comment: Any idea on the kernel update @user1539692. Why would kernel update reset the driver interaction?

Comment: I think 4.17.1-41701 may be way 'older' than 4.17.0-999, despite the date, in that it's a 4.17 kernel.  The -999 suffix indicates it's a prerelease for the next kernel, i.e. 4.18.  If you want to update, do so from a recent http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily, at least until 4.18 is released.

Comment: Tried about five various kernel versions, OpenGL renderer still llvmpipe. Any idea how to detect where things go wrong? Ie, log message etc.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this questsion is as follows:

a) You need ucode files not existing in Ubuntu 18.04, namely those: https://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/vegam/ - they need to go to /lib/firmware/amdgpu

b) You need a kernel that includes vega m patches. Those are currently pending to be including into drm-next. Hopefully they make it into kernel 4.18. If you build from source, here you go: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/linux/log/?h=drm-next-4.18-wip - you can use kernel-package to build it (make-kpkg ...) When you install kernel and updated firmware, make sure to run sudo update-initramfs -u

c) I suggest using mesa 18.1 or later. Paulo has that version in his ppa: https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa

On the hades canyon NUC at hand we disabled the Intel-GPU in Bios. After above steps everything was working - including hevc-10 bit decoding via vaapi.

Comment: If you added the 'nomodeset' you also have to remove that again. When running vulkaninfo, I'm getting an VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER.. does that work for you ? Also colors on VLC when playing a movie appear to be broken.

Comment: Built kernel successfully, two problems: 1) the graphics is super laggy at login screen 2) glmark2 still shows using llvmpipe

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible updated recipe, no promises:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
sudo apt dist-upgrade        # pulls new mesa from above ppa
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18-rc5/linux-headers-4.18.0-041800rc5_4.18.0-041800rc5.201807152130_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18-rc5/linux-headers-4.18.0-041800rc5-generic_4.18.0-041800rc5.201807152130_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18-rc5/linux-image-unsigned-4.18.0-041800rc5-generic_4.18.0-041800rc5.201807152130_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18-rc5/linux-modules-4.18.0-041800rc5-generic_4.18.0-041800rc5.201807152130_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb
wget -m -np https://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/vegam/
sudo cp people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/vegam/*.bin /lib/firmware/amdgpu
sudo /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -u -k all
```

That black screens here when booting on the lower powered hades canyon (with the i7-8705g), but is said to work with the higher powered hades canyon (with the i7-8809g).  You can use the grub menu to get back to the stock kernel.

Also, if you need to update the BIOS to 0044, see https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/126141/Intel-NUC-Kit-NUC8i7HNK and https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005636/mini-pcs.html

Comment: I've been upgrading my Kernel every now and then, what do you think is better about the ubuntu-x mesa over the oibaf drivers? Are you noticing better performance? Doing these steps should we remove the oibaf mesa?

Comment: This worked for me. I also repeated it with kernel 4.18-rc6 with success. My only remaining graphical issue with my NUC8i7HNK is that it fails to resume after suspend (graphics are garbled and there seems to be no way to recover except for a hard reboot via the power switch).

Comment: The suspend issue (mentioned in my previous comment) is resolved when updating the above instructions to use 4.19-rc1. It can be found at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19-rc1/