# NUC8i7HNK1 and Ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, intel, intel-nuc

Has anybody gotten a NUC8i7HNK1 to work with a linux distro? Command line only would suffice. I have tried 16.04 with no succcess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, works with 18.04 - with some restrictions. I turned off the GPU in the BIOS.
Out of the box this graphics card will only be supported with Kernel 4.18 - likely to be early September.

You can also try the RC releases see:
[Graphics drivers for Intel NUC Hades Canyon NUC8i7HVK (AMD Radeon RX Vega GH)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040440/graphics-drivers-for-intel-nuc-hades-canyon-nuc8i7hvk-amd-radeon-rx-vega-gh?rq=1)

Comment: I turned off the GPU in the bios and after I select install ubuntu I get a black screen