# Drivers for rx vega m GL?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, display, radeon, devices

I have a hp spectre with an intel® Core™ i7-8705G CPU and an AMD radeon RX Vega GL discrete graphics card. I can't for the life of me figure out how to switch to my discrete card. My system doesn't even register that another graphics provider exists.

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x48 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 6 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

There was a post some time back about a similar problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040440/graphics-drivers-for-intel-nuc-hades-canyon-nuc8i7hvk-amd-radeon-rx-vega-gh) but sadly this solution no longer seems to work.
AMD doesn't even list the drivers for this card on their website so I'm kind of at a loss here.

Looking up the device with lshw at least shows that the hardware is detected

*

```
-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: Display controller
       product: Polaris 22 XL [Radeon RX Vega M GL]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: c0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef iomemory:2f0-2ef memory:2fe0000000-2fefffffff memory:2ff0000000-2ff01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:de400000-de43ffff memory:de440000-de45ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 630
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef iomemory:2f0-2ef irq:126 memory:2ffe000000-2ffeffffff memory:2f80000000-2f8fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Still no replies...

Comment: Will this work on Ubuntu 16.04 as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need **vegam firmware**, **new kernel 4.18** and **mesa-utils amdgpu driver** for ubuntu 18.04.

**Vegam firmware**

```
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/
sudo cp linux-firmware/amdgpu/*.bin /lib/firmware/amdgpu/
sudo /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -u -k all
```

**Kernel 4.18**

See this application to install new kernel. https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Run the ukuu application and install kernel 4.18.17 or most recent one.

**Mesa-utils Driver**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

After reboot, to verify if the vega gl is switchable, run the following command.

```
env DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you. I was losing my mind trying to solve this issue. I was thinking I might have to return this laptop!